# Extracting values from JSON text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

```
{"A":100,
"B":[{"Title":"Age","Match":false},{"Title":"Height","Match":false},{"Title":"Country","Match":false},{"Title":"Gender","Match":false},{"Title":"Language","Match":True}],
"C":78}
```

I have a table in SQL Server database and one column (columnName) has JSON text. I would like to extract values and return result in separate columns.

I tried:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(columnName, $.A) AS Score,        -- This works --
       JSON_VALUE(columnName, $.B.Title...) AS Age, -- How can I access the Age, Match values --
       JSON_VALUE(columnName, $.C) AS FinalScore    -- This works --
```

I think for A and C it worked because they have one value but B has list of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a statement like the following. You should parse the input JSON with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema (columns definitions):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (JsonData varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data (JsonData)
VALUES ('{"A":100,
"B":[{"Title":"Age","Match":false},{"Title":"Height","Match":false},{"Title":"Country","Match":false},{"Title":"Gender","Match":false},{"Title":"Language","Match":true}],
"C":78}')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j1.A, j1.C, j2.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (d.JsonData) WITH (
   A int '$.A',
   B nvarchar(max) '$.B' AS JSON,
   C int '$.C'
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.B) WITH (
   Title varchar(500) '$.Title',
   Match bit '$.Match'
) j2
```

Result:

```
A   C   Title    Match
100 78  Age      False
100 78  Height   False
100 78  Country  False
100 78  Gender   False
100 78  Language True
```

Note, that the reason for the `NULL` results is the fact, that `B` key in the input JSON is a JSON array, so you need to use `JSON_QUERY()` to get the whole JSON array and additional `CROSS APPLY` to parse this array. `JSON_VALUE()` extracts a scalar value from a `JSON` string and if the `path` points to not a scalar value, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode.

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(d.JsonData, '$.A') AS A,
   JSON_QUERY(d.JsonData, '$.B') AS B,
   JSON_VALUE(d.JsonData, '$.C') AS C,
   j.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.JsonData, '$.B') WITH (
   Title varchar(500) '$.Title',
   Match bit '$.Match'
) j
```